# How to make a Facebook search request to find Locations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I use Facebook C# SDK. I try to make a Facebook search request to retrieve locations without success.

I don't know all the parameters which can be used in a "search" request.

I use this code:

```
Dictionary<string,object> searchParams = new Dictionary<string,object>(); 
searchParams.Add("q", "Orange");    
searchParams.Add("type", "place");      
searchParams.Add("country", "France");      

FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(token); 
var searchedPlaces = fbClient.Get("/search", searchParams);
```

I receive a response with some places everywhere in the world not only in France!! 
The filters "category" and "country" have no effect.

Which parameters can be used in the request ? Where find the parameters list for a search request?

How to fix parameters "category", "country" and what write in the parameter "q"?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

The example search for places is given as `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000` - you'll need an access token but otherwise that works fine for me; the response shows Coffee shops centered around those coordinates

{edit}
The only search options are

1. `q` for a text based query
2. `center` (with coordinates) and `distance` to specify the approximate location
3. Both of the above

Comment: this response does not answer my questions. It lists only the contents of the documentation.

Comment: I thought you were asking about the filters 'category' and 'country' which as far as I know don't exist - I'll see if i can find a complete list

Comment: edited - the example in the documentation lists all possible search options for places